# Package dependency error "there is no package called ‘stringi’"

Tags: r, dependencies, devtools, r-package, stringi

I created an R package and loaded it to github ([microdadosBrasil](https://github.com/lucasmation/microdadosBrasil)). When I try to install the package (as a user would) I get the following error:

```
devtools::install_github("lucasmation/microdadosBrasil")
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringi’
```

I tried solving this by adding **stringi** to the package dependencies 
In DESCRIPTION in included:

```
Imports:
    stringi
```

I also included the package import at NAMESPACE

```
import(stringi)
```

But, even then I get the same installation error. 
To be hones I'm not even aware of any explicit function in my package that uses the `stringi` package.

If I install `stringi` before then the `microdadosBrasil` installation works:

```
install.packages('stringi')
devtools::install_github("lucasmation/microdadosBrasil")
```

This is the session information when error occurs (before pre-installing  `stringi`)

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to dependencies of packages because one package calls file in another package and so on (like recursion). So first try to install all dependencies of the package then definitely this package will work.