# Issue with R package check on Windows: package suggested but not available: 'stringi'

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I have built an R package in RStuio under MAC OS, and upon checking it via devtools::check() I got no problems (0 Erros, 0 warnings, 0 notes).

I ran into an issue when testing it under Windows. No function out of my package makes use of the 'stringi' package, yet I got this error:

```
> E  checking package dependencies    Package suggested but not
> available: 'stringi'
>        The suggested packages are required for a complete check.    Checking can be attempted without them by setting the environment   
> variable _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_ to a false value.
```

This error only crops out when testing my package under Windows. I have made some web search and I couldn't find a proper solution. The only similar thing I have found is an earlier post in this same forum (
[Package dependency error "there is no package called ‘stringi’"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705714/package-dependency-error-there-is-no-package-called-stringi)) but no solution that can fit my situation has been proposed.

I have tried to include 'stringi' either within my package's Depends, Imports, or Suggests, but that could not fix the issue. In the second case (Imports), upon checking the package, I got an error message saying that the 'stringi' package were not required by any of my implemented functions.

Is there any viable practical solution to the issue?

Should that may help, these are the packages listed as Imports in my package's DESCRIPTION:

```
Imports:
    ca (>= 0.70),
    classInt (>= 0.2-3),
    cluster (>= 2.0.7),
    FactoMineR (>= 1.40),
    ggplot2 (>= 3.0.0),
    ggrepel (>= 0.8.0),
    graphics (>= 3.4.3),
    Hmisc (>= 4.1-1),
    RcmdrMisc (>= 1.0),
    reshape2 (>= 1.4.3),
    stats (>= 3.4.3),
    utils (>= 3.4.3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages can also have dependencies themselves,
which become transitive dependencies of your package.
You can use the `remotes` package to find them:

```
library(remotes)
deps <- package_deps("ggplot2")
deps$package
 [1] "assertthat"   "cli"          "colorspace"   "crayon"       "dichromat"    "digest"       "fansi"        "ggplot2"     
 [9] "glue"         "gtable"       "labeling"     "lazyeval"     "magrittr"     "munsell"      "pillar"       "plyr"        
[17] "R6"           "RColorBrewer" "Rcpp"         "reshape2"     "rlang"        "scales"       "stringi"      "stringr"     
[25] "tibble"       "utf8"         "viridisLite"  "withr"
```

You can see that `ggplot2` depends (transitively) on `stringi`.

You have to install all transitive dependencies to check your package,
in each machine where you want to check.
You should be able to do that by running `update(dev_package_deps(dependencies=TRUE))` after opening your package project in RStudio.

EDIT: nevertheless, I've had this same problem when a package is updated on CRAN,
it takes a few days for everything to normalize.
`stringi` was updated yesterday (2018-07-20).

Comment: Hello. Your suggestion fixed the issue when testing my package on my MAC (R CMD check results 0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes) and on my Windows-based PC (R CMD check results 0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes). Still, I am wondering how my package is supposed to pass the CRAN tests. In fact, I have used the 'rhub' package to run one of the tests the package would undergo should it be submitted to CRAN, and I got a red flag: Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :  there is no package called 'stringi'. So, I am back to square one.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem on CRAN. `rhub` can be hit or miss, try using `devtools::build_win(version = c("R-release", "R-devel"))`. Check also [this reference](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/release.html).

Comment: To elaborate: that shouldn't be a problem on CRAN if all transitive dependencies are available there, but sometimes packages get "temporarily lost" after they are updated, and you get those errors about missing packages. Give it a day or two to normalize.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your advises and got no issue in testing the package on my windows-based pc. Also, I have run devtools::build_win(version = c("R-release", "R-devel")), and after 30 min I got two reports in which there was no trace of the 'stringi' dependency issue. Thank you. I learned a lot today.